# How to enable "stop if true" option in conditional formatting rule in xlsx using Apache XSSF format

Tags: apache-poi, xssf

I am unable to find "stop if true" option to be checked in XSSFSheet . However with HSSF by default it is checked.

The problem here is "stop if true" option is not enabled then XSSF cell is showing with background color as black(which I was set). In HSSF, by default this option is enabled so HSSF cell value is displayed without any background color.

I am using apache poi 3.16 version

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the next code

```
sheet.getCTWorksheet().getConditionalFormattingArray(0).getCfRuleArray(0).setStopIfTrue(true);
```

If you're using XSSFSheet for sheets.